# Compiler Error Assumed value of MB_LEN_MAX wrong

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ubuntu-16.04

I'm currently trying to run [this image segmentation program](http://cs.brown.edu/people/pfelzens/segment/index.html), but I'm having errors when I try to compile it. To compile, you just `make`, which runs the command

```
g++ -g -O3 -I. -o segment segment.cpp -lm
```

However, it runs into a compilation error -- its output is

```
In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:887:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/cwchar:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/fstream:38,
                 from ./pnmfile.h:27,
                 from segment.cpp:23:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wchar2.h:448:3: error: #error "Assumed value of MB_LEN_MAX wrong"
 # error "Assumed value of MB_LEN_MAX wrong"
   ^~~~~
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'segment' failed
make: *** [segment] Error 1
```

Here is the relevant area of `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wchar2.h`

```
  /* We would have to include <limits.h> to get a definition of MB_LEN_MAX.
     But this would only disturb the namespace.  So we define our own
     version here.  */
#define __WCHAR_MB_LEN_MAX  16
#if defined MB_LEN_MAX && MB_LEN_MAX != __WCHAR_MB_LEN_MAX
# error "Assumed value of MB_LEN_MAX wrong"
#endif
  if (__bos (__s) != (size_t) -1 && __WCHAR_MB_LEN_MAX > __bos (__s))
    return __wcrtomb_chk (__s, __wchar, __ps, __bos (__s));
  return __wcrtomb_alias (__s, __wchar, __ps);
}
```

And the relevant areas of `segment.cpp`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <image.h>
#include <misc.h>
#include <pnmfile.h> //<-- Line 23 of segment.cpp, where the error occurs
#include "segment-image.h"
```

and `pnmfile.h`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream> //<-- Line 27 of pnmfile.h where the error occurs
#include "image.h"
#include "misc.h"
```

Does anyone know what's causing this error (and if so, how to fix it)? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with g++ 6.4.0. Thank you for any help you can give!

EDIT: I've confirmed that fstream does work. I compiled the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream is("in.txt");
    int a, b;
    is >> a >> b;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with the same command

```
g++ -g -O3 -I. -o temp.exe temp.cpp -lm
```

and it successfully printed out two integers read from a text file.

Comment: Where is the relevant section of *your* code ?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can build a simple program including `<fstream>`? This way you can easily figure out whether the issue is with your environment or the project itself.

Comment: SidS: the error is thrown during the include; I'm sorry if that was unclear. I've added in the relevant lines above.



Frank: I threw together a simple program using <fstream> and it ran with no errors (I've included it above for convenience).

Comment: The headers of that project have a number of `#define` in them. It's possible that one of them is conflicting with some identifiers in your STL implementation. It's pretty hard to diagnose, but since the project is so small, you might be able to get away with prefixing them.

Comment: @Helium_1s2 Also, a quick SO hint: if you prefix people's name with @ in comments, they will get a notification, this way, it won't take 21 hours for them to notice you answered their question :P

Comment: I didn't want to bother you guys. I'll make sure to tag you next time!

Comment: I think perhaps you should be #including `limits` rather than `climits`.  `climits` is for C, not C++.

Comment: @PaulSanders Switching to `limits` (and adding `#define UCHAR_MAX std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()` at the top so it still worked without a lot of changes) fixed the compile errors, and produced a badly formatted output file. Fortunately, changing one incorrect value in the ppm output file with a text editor solved the problem! Here are the input and output images, for your viewing pleasure. Thanks for the help! https://imgur.com/a/o7Y2NW6 https://imgur.com/a/S0VfkZm

Comment: @Frank Coming back to this question a month later because the issue popped up again. It turns out my `/usr/local/include/limits.h` has `#define MB_LEN_MAX 1`. Ironically, the version in `/usr/include/limits.h` defines it to 16 and has a comment saying "We define this value here since the gcc header does not define the correct value." Changing the value to 16 in the other version of limits.h fixes the problem, but that's more of a bandaid than a real solution. Is there a way to force gcc to use the correct version? Would I be better off creating a new stackoverflow question for this? Thanks :)

Comment: @Helium_1s2, yes, you might be better off asking the more specific question by itself, just make sure you produce a proper MCVE.

Comment: You are better off removing /usr/local altogether. Do not, i repeat, not, under any circumstances, install *anything* to /usr/local. It is for experienced system administrators only. You will wreak your system faster than you can say `make uninstall`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `limits.h` **from the same libc** from which your `bits/wchar2.h` is coming. If you check the comment in the [latter file](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=wcsmbs/bits/wchar2.h#l443) just above the `#error` which you are getting, you'll see why - it serves as a safeguard against mixing incompatible header files.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of longtime issues is my motivation to build my own Linux distro.
Googling gets you nowhere. But ... building your own (cross) compiler
solves the problem. Compiler has it own definition in his relevant headers  MB_LEN_MAX  1
MB_LEN_MAX  16 in glibc includes. No problem.